# Why in jupyter-notebook with python3 kernel , sys.version show 2.7.2, not python3.x

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, kernel

In jupyter notebook, I use python3 kernel, but i type sys.version, it show 
2.7.2 ... ,i expected 3.x

```
import sys, platform
sys.version
'2.7.12 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:36:49) \n[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]'
platform.python_version()
'2.7.12'
```

I expect the output  to be 3.x, but the actual output is 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your terminal type the following to check if you indeed have kernels setup the right way, for e.g. mine shows following

```
schlator@lenovo:~$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  ir           /home/schlator/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/ir
  julia-1.0    /home/schlator/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/julia-1.0
  python2      /home/schlator/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2
  python3      /home/schlator/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

If you see something unexpected, you may have to install the python3 kernel.

Comment: ＠Schlator, i modify the kernel json file, got the right version of python with python3 kernel, but disconnect always, do you have an good idea? thanks